# How to measure horizontal plane surface(visible in camera) using ARKit-Scenekit before placing objects?

Tags: scenekit, ios11, xcode9-beta, arkit

I want to measure the horizontal plane surface to find whether it fits the object that i am going to place. For ex. if i am going to place a cot 3D model(with fixed size) in a room using iOS 11 ARKit,

First i want to detect if that room surface is sufficient or not to place my 3D model by measuring the surface area(width and height etc.)

Second if the user tries to place it without sufficient place, i should not allow him to place the cot and show him error message.

I created a sample POC by following https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/PlacingObjects.zip using which i am able to detect the horizontal plane and place the cot. But the issue is whatever may be the surface, user is able to place the cot which shouldn't be allowed in real time.

I saw couple of demos in which they say we can measure the size of the room or a horizontal plane(https://www.curbed.com/2017/6/29/15894556/ar-measure-app-augmented-reality-ruler-measuring-tape-ios)

I am using ARKit Scenekit inorder to achieve this and i am new to AR and Scenekit. I need to know if this is doable, and if so how to achieve it.

Comment: Are you able to solve this? if you can please share your solution for this?

Comment: Not exactly. I followed what rickster suggested. Create a border and let user decide whether it fits or not. No luck on detecting the obstacles in surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* estimate the size of a detected plane by inspecting its dimensions. But you shouldn't.

ARKit has plane estimation, not scene reconstruction. That is, it'll tell you there's a flat surface at *(some point)* and that said surface **probably** extends **at least** *(some distance)* from that point. It doesn't know exactly how big the surface is (it's even refining its estimate over time), and it doesn't tell you where there are interruptions in that continuous surface, much less the size and shape of such interruptions.

In fact, if you're looking at the floor and moving around, and you see one patch of floor, then another patch of floor on the other side of a solid wall from the first, ARKit will happily recognize that those two patches are coplanar and merge them into the same anchor. At the same time, neither detected patch may cover the entire extent of the floor around it.

If you attempt to restrict where the user can place virtual objects in AR based on plane estimates, you're likely to frustrate them with two kinds of error: you'll have areas where it looks to the user like they can place something but that don't allow it, and you'll have areas that look like they should be off-limits that do allow placing things.

Instead, design your experience to involve the user in deciding where the sensible places for content are. See [this demo](http://www.madewitharkit.com/post/163259313638/arkit-furniture-dropping-app-by) for example — ARKit detects the *level* of the floor (not its boundaries), then uses that to show UI indicating the size/shape of objects to be placed. It's up to the user to make sure there's enough room for the couch, etc.

---

<sub>As for the technical how-to on what you probably shouldn't do: The docs for [`ARPlaneAnchor.extent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arplaneanchor/2882055-extent) say that the x and z coordinates of that vector are the width and length of the estimated plane. And all units in ARKit are meters. (Which is width and which is length? It's a matter of perspective. And of the rotation encoded in the anchor's `transform`.)</sub>

Comment: WoW!! the link http://www.madewitharkit.com/post/163259313638/arkit-furniture-dropping-app-by you have posted is really helpful. Can you please direct me on how to exactly achieve this using ARKit? Do we need to draw the circle and boundary based on the object size? If there is a tutorial or link that at least gives a starting point would be really helpful since i am very new to AR.

Comment: Is that focus square or rectangle(in the demo - http://www.madewitharkit.com/post/163259313638/arkit-furniture-dropping-app-by ) built in such a way that it identifies floor or plane surface alone? That is if i hold the camera focusing the ceiling, still will it allow me to place the furniture?

Comment: I'm not the one who built that demo, so I can't say what they did. Generally, though: In theory, ARKit plane estimation also can detect planes above the camera facing down. In practice, it doesn't seem to do well at finding ceilings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have implemented the same way the demo has been built. Now i am showing a border after which i am allowing user to place the object. Is it possible to identify if that border is completely placed in a plane surface instead of some obstacle? Like if i have my floor space limited to 10 meters with walls on both the sides and the border (of the object) i drew is 12 meters long, it overlaps with the walls. In this case can we identify the overlapping? If so how to do it?